# Assure the continuation of rivers (raster dataset)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, rivers, cost-surface

I am creating a cost surface raster for identifying least cost paths for road constructions. One of the factors influencing the cost is water cover. I am using Landsat based Global Surface Water raster dataset for water cover. In some cases the rivers on the raster dataset do not have continuation and they break, messing up my least cost paths (assuming that on the break point there is no water, but there is).

How can I assure the continuation of rivers?

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.3.
[image]

Comment: Can you not look at using something like the SRTM elevation data to define rivers and see if there is any correlation between the Landsat imagery and the derived rivers?

Comment: Another idea perhaps tedious: with ArcMap editor, digitize a polygon fitting the river foot print. And then do a polygon to raster conversion.  Where the rivers disappear, set the _new river raster_ to some value and generate a combined raster with _new river raster_ cells replacing the disappearing rivers in the large raster. And run you cost model on this. Was able to generate the _river raster_ , but I did carry through to the end to get your objective.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers. The problem is that I have many rivers and I would have to check them one by one. In the end, I think I will correct them using the Openstreetmaps data on rivers.

Comment: You do not say where in the world your processing is? A river has width so as soon as it goes below 30m (resolution of Landsat) this is going to introduce breaks. Sounds like you are really after a polygon dataset? Try contacting the national mapping agency? If the data you are processing is in the USA then looking into their NHD dataset.